# Excel Color Coding based on certain values

Tags: excel

I want to assign Color Values to Lines based on certain value comparisons. Attached pic for reference.
[Excel Color Coding Explanation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKBO5.png)
The example I have provided is where I have set the color coding manually. The coding on the spreadsheet is not exactly correct.
The Colors should depend on the Explanation I have provided.
Please let me know which formulas to apply in which cell and how so the Color Coding applies automatically.
Thanks in advance!!

[It seems to be working on rows but not all. Ive highlighted the parts with the desired color to illustrate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpP1J.png)

Comment: I added an image file explaining the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in conditional formatting. Each should apply to the whole array of cells. Ensure that the first row of the row matches the row number used in the formulas. The key here is the row number lineup and the $ to lock the reference to the column but for the whole row.

You also need to highlight the whole array to which you want it to apply before putting in the formulas. If you change it after you put in the formulas the cell references may change and you will need to paste them in again.
`==OR($M4<>"",$M4<>0)` with green fill 
`=AND($I4<0,OR($M3="",$M3=0))` with red fill
`=AND($I4<$L4,$M4="")` with orange fill 
`=AND($L4>$L4,OR($M4=0,$M4=""))` with no fill (you do need to go in and select no fill

[image]